# Can Young modulus be small for high-frequencies but large for low-frequencies?

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

Carbon bicycle frames have the unusual property that they are superior to aluminum frames in high-frequency absorption. A cyclist on a carbon-frame bike will feel tarmac chatter far less than on an aluminum-frame bike.

Yet carbon frames are also famously solid. A carbon-frame bike will remains solid underneath a cyclist using arm muscles, efficiently transferring all their power to the drivetrain with little perceptible frame bending.

Are there materials that have a small Young modulus when subjected to high frequency stresses, but that have a large Young modulus under low frequency stresses? (And could the carbon fibers used on bike frames be one such material?)

Comment: It's much more likely that the modulus doesn't change appreciably, but the damping does.  I.e., the material isn't floppier at high frequencies, but rather that any flexing that does happen has a higher tendency to turn to heat.  Aluminum is famous for having very low damping, to the point where an acquaintance of mine fixed a problem in a control system by ordering a part's material be changed to magnesium (famously dead) from aluminum.

Comment: (Not writing that as an answer because your question isn't "why does carbon fiber not transmit high-frequency vibrations").

Comment: @TimWescott Maybe I was not asking the right question. I'm happy to modify the question in any way, just so long as the answer would provide a rational/physical explanation for this puzzle https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/77812/48599. For instance: How could carbon be so good at damping, yet be so unyielding?

Comment: Well, you could edit this question to ask your "good at damping yet unyielding" question -- I think that's a good phrasing.  It may not answer all of your question, but it'll be a start.  This _might_ be better over at engineering.stackexchange.com, but maybe not.  It really depends on whether you want the theoretical molecular-level answers (here), or the bulk materials answers (there).

Comment: @TimWescott Cool.. Let's first see if there is a convincing answer at the bulk level (https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/54904/36266), and if additional clarity is needed, I'll ask here again. Meanwhile, I'll shortly delete the present question. Thanks for your feedback.